# Negative Discount does not apply on category page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have made it possible to apply a negative Discount in the cataloge rules.

After that, i modified the Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer by the following code:

```
if ($this->_rulePrices[$key]!==false) {
 // $finalPrice = min($product->getData('final_price'),    $this->_rulePrices[$key]);
    $finalPrice = $this->_rulePrices[$key];
    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
}
```

Now i can increase the price for example by 5%. The price is increased in the cart and on detail side of the article. But in the category page, only special prices get increased. When a product have a normal price, the price does not get modified.